# Number of Ways to Fill a Matrix with symbols subject to Weird contsraint.

Tags: combinatorics

Got this problem from a friend and would like some pointers if anyone has any.

Fill an $n \times n$ matrix with the symbols $\{a,b,c,d\}$ subject to the following:

Only the symbol $a$ appears to the left or above an $a$

Only the symbol $b$ appears to the right or above a $b$

Only the symbol $c$ appears to the left or below a $c$

Only the symbol $d$ appears to the right or below a $d$

Here are some examples of a valid fillings:
$$\left( \begin{matrix} a & a & b  & b \\ a & a & b & b \\ c & c & c & d \\  c & c & c & d  \end{matrix}\right) $$

$$\left( \begin{matrix} a & a & a  & a & a & b  & b \\ a & a & a  & a & a & b  & b \\ a & a & a & d & d & d & d \\  a & a & a & d & d & d & d\\a & a & d & d & d & d & d\\c & c & d & d & d & d & d\\  c & c & d & d & d & d & d  \end{matrix} \right) $$

What I have done: We'll it is clear to me that the $a$'s (for example) make up a sort of Young Diagram just by the property above. But there is more to the problem than that. If your YT for $a$ is just a square, then you might have a reversed (right justified) YT available to place for the $b$'s. Details like this seem to make this a tricky problem for me. I am intrigued by this problem and I just thought I'd share it here in case there is some easy way to do this counting problem that I've never heard of.

Thanks,

Comment: If I'm counting correctly, the first few values (starting with $n=1$) are $4$, $25$, $120$, $497$, $1924$, $7265$, $27288$, $102745$, $388692$, $1477721$, $5643064$, $21632785$, $83204260$, $320932177$. This sequence isn't in OEIS. [Here's the code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/4d0b2d862d9e598a71282e98641e8b4a) I used.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will have to parse your code for a bit to see if I can understand what your algorithm is.

Comment: It's backtracking, filling the matrix from left to right and top to bottom, checking at each position which of the four possible letters is compatible with the ones already placed above and to the left of it. The first and second bit of the letter code specify whether the letter needs to extend left or right and above or below, respectively.

Comment: Thanks. I worked through your code and I think I understand it pretty well now. If you want to answerify your comment I'll gladly accept it. I was looking for a way to count this and you've provided a way. Thanks again.

Comment: OK, I did. I thought you were looking for a way to do it without a computer and was just trying to help by providing some numbers :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answerified comment as requested:

If I'm counting correctly, the first few values (starting with $n=1$) are $4$, $25$, $120$, $497$, $1924$, $7265$, $27288$, $102745$, $388692$, $1477721$, $5643064$, $21632785$, $83204260$, $320932177$. This sequence isn't in OEIS.

[Here's the code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/4d0b2d862d9e598a71282e98641e8b4a) I used.

Comment: There may well be a 'faster' way but this is what I wanted. I seem to have a blind spot for getting started on these types of counting problems. Thanks.

Comment: I think this is: $8 {2n \choose n}   - 3 n^2 -2n - 7$ Combinatorics is weird.

Comment: @amcalde: Wow, nice!! Did you find that from my numbers or by counting?

Comment: I started with your code. Then added in short-cuts in the code (like if you put down a $d$ to begin with then you are all done. And very slowly arrived to the point where I got things down to weird looking sums. Finding the right binomial coefficients was another chore, then summing those eventually led to the answer. I was very surprised it boiled down so nicely.

Comment: @amcalde: So do you have a complete derivation? Are you going to post it?

Comment: I may. I don't have time right now. But I may add it as another answer perhaps this weekend.

Comment: @amcalde: This question was justed posted again: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818684. Do you think you might find the time to post the derivation of your amazing result?

Comment: I will try tonight and tomorrow. I need to save more of my old work!

Comment: I'm sorry to report that after a few attempts I have not been able to prove this. I left no trail of bread crumbs when I first wandered down the path to this 'answer'. I believe it is correct but cannot seem to reprove it while tracing my steps.

Comment: @amcalde: Too bad. Gabriel Burns' answer looks like it might lead to a proof if the remaining errors are fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how amcalde did it, but after thinking about it some more, I have a derivation, which I've translated to match this formulation of the problem, rather than the one I posted.

Note: this answer is wrong, though I feel like I covered every case without double-counting.  I only post it because I think it's close, and maybe someone can see what went wrong with it too arrive at the correct derivation.

(update: I thought I had it for a second, after I got the correct result for the first couple values.  It's not the same form amcalde got, though and they aren't equivalent)

We attack it case-by-case...

In the following, "opposite symbol" means diagonally opposite, so $a$ and $d$ are opposites, as are $b$ and $c$.

for cases 1-5, we assume that each symbol is configured in a rectangle (i.e. the number of a given symbol in each row is either $0$ or $k$ for some $k\le n$ and likewise (with possibly different $k$) for each column):

Case 1: there is only one unique symbol in the matrix.  there are $4$ of these.

Case 2: every column (or every row) contains only one unique symbol, with two unique symbols in the array as a whole.  there are $n-1$ ways to choose the first column of the second symbol, times $4$ ways to choose the symbols, times $2$ to count the same thing for rows for a total of $8n-8$

Case 3:some columns (or rows) contain (the same) 2 distinct symbols, and the rest contain only a single (different) distinct symbol. using similar counting to the above, there are $8(n-1)^2$ of these.

Case 4: there are four distinct symbols in the matrix and no symbol shares a column or row with its opposite. there are $(n-1)^2$ of these.

Case 5: there are four distinct symbols and two opposite symbols appear together in at least one column or row (but not both, because of the rectangle requirement).  There are $4(n-1){{n-1} \choose 2}=2(n-1)(n-1)(n-2)=(2n-4)(n-1)^2$ of these.

all other configurations belong to case 6.

Case 6: at least one column and at least one row contains two opposite symbols. In other words, at least one symbol fails to form a rectangle shape.

This is the tough one, but suppose for a second that we're talking about $a$ and $d$.  Each such case will correspond to a reflection $a \iff c$ and $b \iff d$, so we'll just multiply by two when we're done.  Now imagine drawing a line between every $a$ and $d$ that appear in the same row or column.  this will form a stairstep-shaped line going from lower right to upper left.  If there are $k$ rows and $r$ columns consisting of $a$ and $d$, then this is a classic stars-and-bars problem with ${k+r} \choose r$ possibilities for the shape of the stairstep. The number of different places a stairstep can be placed is a source of potential pitfalls.  To simplify it we assume at first that our stairstep starts with a horizontal line (we'll double our result again, and start our sum at $k=0$), and count the number of a stairstep that ends with a vertical line (we'll also start at $ r=0 $) can be placed. There are $n-r-1$ horizontal positions.  There are also $n-k-1$ vertical positions, in all but one of which the stairstep can optionally be extended with an additional horizontal line, so the total number of possible stairsteps is

$$4\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\left((2n-2k-3)\sum_{r=0}^{n-2}\left({{r+k} \choose r}(n-r-1)\right)\right)$$$$=4\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\left((2n-2k-3){{k+n} \choose {k+2}}\right)$$$$=4\left(3{{2n-1} \choose n}-2n^2+n-2\right)=6{{2n} \choose n}-8n^2+4n-8$$

Adding it all up we get $$6{{2n} \choose n}-8n^2+4n-8+(2n+5)(n-1)^2+8n-8+4= 6{{2n} \choose n}+2n^3-7n^2+4n-7$$

Comment: "$a$ and $d$ are opposites, as are $b$ and $d$" -- you mean $b$ and $c$?

Comment: yup I'll fix it. Along with another error I just found, though I'm not sure if that will fix the count.

Comment: I think you didn't take into account that each $k$ and $r$ can occur in various positions ($n-k+1$ and $n-r+1$)?

Comment: I think you're right.  I'll crunch those numbers and see how it turns out.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to simplify the resulting sum $$\sum_{k=1}^n{(1-k+n)\left(\sum_{r=0}^n {{{r+k} \choose {r}}(1-r+n)}\right)}$$ but I plugged it into wolfram alpha and (after breaking it up so that it had enough time to compute) came up with $${18 - 63 n - 95 n^2 - 39 n^3 + 4 n^4 + 6 n^5 + n^6 - 3 ((2 - 7 n + n^3) {{3 + 2 n}\choose {2 + n})}/{3 (2 + n) (3 + n)} - n (1 + n)^2)/2$$, so the result is not nearly as clean as the OP's.  It may or may not be equivalent after the $-2{{2n} \choose {n}}$ and adding the other cases, but I don't know.  Alpha didn't get as far as checking values.)

Comment: That last one should be $$ {{18-6n-95n^2-39n^3+4n^4+6n^5+n^6-3 \left((2-7n+n^3) {{3 + 2 n} \choose {2 + n}}\right)}\over {3 (2 + n) (3 + n)}} - {{n (1 + n)^2}\over 2}$$

Comment: Simplified it to $$2 {{2n+3} \choose {n+1}}- {{(n+3)(n^2+3n+4)} - {n(n+1)^2}\over 2}$$

Comment: so, the last formula in the comments, if it's correct, which it may or may not be, should be substituted for the first formula listed in the answer under case 6 (the sum that evaluates to ${{2(n+1)} \choose {n+1}}-2(n+1)$).  I haven't put it in there, because I'm still unsure if it's correct, and I don't currently have time to do all the simplifying and error-searching such that it would take.  Honestly, if this answer is to be any help to you, it's probably just in the approach to breaking down the cases, as I have an unfortunate tendency to make careless errors in my actual calculations.

Comment: for clarity, I'll throw it in there, but leave it unsimplified and unchecked for the moment.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's still wrong.  The sum I have for case 6 now accounts for position of the stairstep patterns, but assumes there are the same number of positions for each pattern. Unfortunately, a stairstep that starts with starts and ends with horizontal lines can be placed in only $(n-k-1)$ vertical positions, while one that starts horizontal and ends vertical has $(n-k)$ and one that starts and ends vertical has (n-k+1).  The symmetry of the problem may balance this out, but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: So I just fixed (I thought) the position count, and the results are simplifying much better, but still wrong.  Frustrating.