# Counting divisions of an $n \times n$ grid

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science

I'm looking for an efficient way to count the number of ways $D_n$ to divide an $n \times n$ grid into four (possibly empty) regions: top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right, such that no cell of another region is in either of the designated directions from a cell of a given region, e. g. no cell from a different region is either above or to the left of a cell in the top left region.

I can see that a region will either be rectangular (possibly degenerate) or will share a (possibly irregular) stairstep-shaped border with the opposite region, in which case the other two regions will necessarily be rectangular.  I thus thought to count the number of stairstep paths between (possibly identical) points on an $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ lattice, which I know would be $$2\left(\sum _{k=1}^n\sum_{r=1}^n {{k+r} \choose k} + (n + 1){{n+1} \choose 2}\right)+(n+1)^2$$ which, when simplified is$$n^3+3n^2-n-3+2{{2n+2}\choose {n+1}}$$

This needs to be adjusted for overcounting (and undercounting), though: divisions with all rectangular regions where one or more are degenerate have a many-to-many correspondence with paths, but I'm having a bit of trouble with the exact corrections to make.

I'm actually trying to compute this as part of a larger calculation, so I'd like to find ways to improve the time-complexity of the algorithm.  In this particular case, for $n>2$, when I'm trying to calculate $D_n$, I'll already know $D_a$ and $D_b$ for some $(a,b)$ where $a+b=n$ so a recurrence relation would be nice.

This is a project Euler problem (or rather isomorphic to one), so I'm looking more for hints/suggestions etc. than actual answers, but any help is appreciated.

Note: in case it wasn't clear, for the purposes of this question, a stairstep path from point $a$ to point $b$ along the lattice in which the distance to point $b$ is strictly decreasing. Paths go both ways, so the path from $a$ to $b$ is equivalent to the reverse path from $b$ to $a$.

update: joriki pointed out that this is the same problem as [Number of Ways to Fill a Matrix with symbols subject to Weird contsraint.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1727653).  That question's page has a closed form, but no derivation.  I am still interested in computing it quickly for large n, though it's worth noting that the answers in this particular case are taken modulo a large number (which I suspect is probably prime), if that changes anything.

Comment: I'm not sure how the definition (or at least your example) allows a stair-step boundary. For example if the boundary between top-left and top-right is not straight up, then one region has a cell with some cell(s) from the other region above it.

Comment: it allows a stairstep boundary only between _opposite_ regions.  The boundaries between adjacent regions will be straight, as you mention.

Comment: e.g.  for $n=3$  with indices starting in the top left corner we could have $\text {top left} = \{0,0\}, \text {top right} = \{(0,1),(0,2),(1,2)\}, \text {bottom left} = \{(1,0), (1,1), (2,0), (2,1)\},$ and $\text {bottom right}=\{(2,2)\}$

Comment: OK thanks, that's clear now.

Comment: if vertices are indexed in the same fashion, the above division would correspond to the path $(1,1)\iff (1,2)\iff(2,2)$ (where $\iff$ represents an edge)

Comment: This is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1727653. The poster of that question gave a closed form in a comment under my answer and said he might add a derivation, but hasn't yet. You might give him a nudge.

Comment: Alright, thanks.  I did look for duplicates, but the titles are dissimilar enough, I didn't find that one.

Comment: @GabrielBurns: Yes, I only found it because I remembered that it says "left", "right", "above", "below" and has my user name in it :-) Shall I close this as a duplicate, or do you want to wait for responses to the approach you described?

Comment: Hmm..  I'm satisfied with his closed form, but my question is two-part. Specifically, I'm still wondering about how to calculate it efficiently.  I'll edit the question to note that, though.

Comment: @GabrielBurns: How do you mean, to calculate it efficiently? Don't you want to use the closed form? That uses a single binomial coefficient; I doubt you'll find a more efficient way to calculate it than that. There's no derivation, but it coincides with the first $14$ numbers that I computed.

Comment: @joriki yeah, you can go ahead and close it.

Comment: @GabrielBurns: OK, I closed it and wrote to the author of the other post asking for the derivation again.